# How can I integrate in cylindrical coordinates with Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I know how to integrate a function with Scipy. I do it in this way:

```
    from scipy import *
    from scipy import integrate
    integral = integrate.simps(y,x)
```

In this way I integrate with the Simpsons' rule the function y(x), but what if I want to integrate this function in cylindrical coordinates?
I mean, instead of the integral   \int y(x)dx I want to solve the integral \int y(x)*2*pi*x*dx.

I tried with

```
    integral = integrate.simps(y,x**2.*pi)
```

But it doesn't seem to return the correct result.

I am integrating data points, not functions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
integral = integrate.simps(y*x*2*pi,x)
```

where `y` should be an array of function values at the positions `x`. Note that `2*pi*x` is the necessary factor to add to your integrand (as you pointed out yourself).